# Add dynamic id to custom row

Tags: php, while-loop

I created a custom grid to have this display :

[image]

Now i need to add an id (with an incremental number) to every row so i can use it as anchor. I tried to regroup every three blocs in one div but i couldn't do it.

```
    <?php
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) { ?>
              <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
              <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
              <div class="projet-bloc-empty col-md-4"><div></div></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="projet-bloc col-md-4">
            <a href="<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
      
      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you want to set an unique ID for each photo you can use the `$i` as an id or the post's id for example `id='image_<?php echo $i; ?>'`

Comment: Not each photo but each row

Comment: What is here a row to you ? If it is the div then you can do something like this: <div id="<?php echo 'row_'.$i; ?>"

Comment: It's still the same idea you can identify each row by using for loop's value or post's id assuming that each post has an unique id.